# Powermock and JAXB causing javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb, powermock, powermockito

I am getting this error when I run the powermock test. I am using java 13 and gradle 6.5.1. Any suggestion with this really help.
This is working fine with hibernate-core 5.3.21.Final and above but not with 5.2.x.

**build.gradle:-**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {

    // hibernate & JPA
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.2.12.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
    }
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.17.Final'


    // junit
    testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1'
    testCompile 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.1'


    // powermock
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.9'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9'

    // jaxb
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**Test class:-**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"jdk.internal.reflect.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.*", "com.sun.*"})
public class PowerTest {
    
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "testApplicationContext.xml"});

    }
}
```

**testApplicationContext.xml:-**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" id = "sessionFactory" >
        <property name = "configLocation">
            <value>hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 5.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-5.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Error log(minimalized):-**

> Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
> resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to
> perform unmarshalling at line number -1 and column -1 in URL
> file:/C:/GitHub/PowerMockTest/build/resources/test/hibernate.cfg.xml.
> Message: unexpected element
> (uri:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg",
> local:"hibernate-configuration"). Expected elements are
> <{}hibernate-configuration>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
> resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to
> perform unmarshalling at line number -1 and column -1 in URL
> file:/C:/GitHub/PowerMockTest/build/resources/test/hibernate.cfg.xml.
> Message: unexpected element
> (uri:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg",
> local:"hibernate-configuration"). Expected elements are
> <{}hibernate-configuration> Caused by:
> org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to
> perform unmarshalling at line number -1 and column -1 in URL
> file:/C:/GitHub/PowerMockTest/build/resources/test/hibernate.cfg.xml.
> Message: unexpected element
> (uri:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg",
> local:"hibernate-configuration"). Expected elements are
> <{}hibernate-configuration>   at
> org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlUrl(ConfigLoader.java:94)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:171)
> at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:283)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:501)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
> ... 87 more Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>
> - with linked exception: [com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; unexpected element (uri:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg",
>   local:"hibernate-configuration"). Expected elements are
>   <{}hibernate-configuration>]  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:483)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:463)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:435)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:126)
>   ... 94 more Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; unexpected
>   element (uri:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg",
>   local:"hibernate-configuration"). Expected elements are
>   <{}hibernate-configuration>   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:741)
>   ... 96 more Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected
>   element (uri:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg",
>   local:"hibernate-configuration"). Expected elements are
>   <{}hibernate-configuration>   ... 108 more